# apply style using attr() to raw html failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function () {
            myhtml = '<tr><td>1</td><td>Orange</td><td>1799.00 x <span>1</span></td><td>0.00</td><td>1799.00</td></tr><tr class="shippingRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Shipping</td><td>2.00</td></tr><tr class="totalRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>1811.00</strong></td></tr>';
            console.log($(myhtml).filter(".shippingRow").find("td").length) // not returning 0;
            $(myhtml).filter(".shippingRow").find("td").attr('style', 'background:red'); // but this doesn't work?!
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to apply style using attr on a raw html, but not sure why it doesn't work. I also tried css(), even remove(), it just can't work, any thought?

Comment: how do you know it's not working?

Comment: You will know its working or not when you append it to `DOM` or `log` it in `console`

Comment: Have you tried using `.css()`?

Comment: thing is, it **DOES** work, as @GuruprasadRao rightly said, you'll find out when you do something to show the fruits of your labours

Comment: @graubnla `I also tried css()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scfknzLr/

Comment: @Sadikhasan.. Your fiddle is not complete, I mean its not full what OP has posted..

Comment: @JaromandaX can u show me a fiddle? I tried append() it doesn't work.

Comment: @AliceXu `it doesn't work` ... what doesn't work? The general jQuery pattern `$(selector).append(html)` definitely does work - can u show me how you tried to use append?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I used append(), and I didn't see any style attached in the DOM.

Comment: you show me yours, and I'll show you where you went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got you wrong, but you have to select the actual rendered table/rows and not just the variable containing it. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/07n3anz7/)

```
$("tbody").find(".shippingRow td").css("background-color", "red");
```